# Pixelformat for image always returns 32 bit

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to get bit depth of PNG images in code. For that i use

`Image ^image;
image->GetPixelFormatSize(image->PixelFormat);`

which always returns 32, although my images are 8-bit, 24-bit and 32-bit.
Am i using the function incorrectly?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/gdipluspixelformats/nf-gdipluspixelformats-getpixelformatsize) function? It is unclear from the question and used tags.

Comment: - and if so, what is the value of `image->PixelFormat` that you pass in?

Comment: I am referring to the image which i create from a file `Image::FromFile(file1->FullName)` and then trying to retrieve properties like width, height, etc which are correct but the bit depth of that image using `image->PixelFormat` prints Format32bppArgb every time. Am i using the wrong function? What would be the right function to get bit depth of image?

Comment: `image->PixelFormat` itself is the pixel format of the image.

Comment: How can I get bit depth of the image and not the pixel format if these two are different things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out. I was creating a bitmap from the file which was assigning it 32bits by default.

Answer (score 1):

image->GetPixelFormatSize(image->PixelFormat);
Returns the color depth, in number of bits per pixel, of the specified pixel format. --